# how to print all the lines of a text file from hash - perl

Tags: perl

I am reading a text file which is having multiple lines in it. I have been assigned a task to print the lines using hash.

```
"\n" is the delimiter we can use.
```

Here is what I tried and got stuck :

**code :**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = ();
my $key;

open (my $fh , "<","test.txt") or die "can not open the file $!\n";

while (my $line =<$fh>)
{
    chomp ($line);
    my($key, $number) = split("\n", $line)
    $hash{$key} = [ $count, $number ];
}
```

i am not able to understand what will be my key in the hash. Can some one help me out to resolve the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "print the lines using hash"? What problem are you trying to solve? Where does `$count` come from?

Comment: Use `use Data::Dumper dumper(keys %hash)` to find it out. I think the key will be the line it self and number will be empty.

Comment: @choroba , Thanks for your reply.. print the lines using hash means output should me printed using hash. i hope i have given the answer

Comment: Unfortunately not. What's the input? How does the expected output look like?

Comment: @choroba input will be each single line or single row which is there in the file

Comment: @user1362796: Unless you can explain your problem better your question will be closed. A hash isn't useful for printing the lines in a file. If you want the contents reformatted somehow then you must show an example

Comment: @ borodin ..Sure .. i will try to put the example

Comment: If you are going to post code, post code that actually compiles and runs. Pasting random gibberish wastes everyone's time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
while (my $line =<$fh>)
```

which reads a single record via `$fh`. The default input record separator in Perl is `"\n"` meaning you are reading the file line-by-line. By definition, a single line has a single line-terminator.

```
chomp ($line);
```

then removes this single `"\n"` from the string in `$line`.

Therefore,

```
my($key, $number) = split("\n", $line);
```

copies `$line` to `$key`, and leaves `$number` undefined as there is no `"\n"` in `$line`. Even if you had not `chomp`ed the line, `$number` would not contain anything useful because the line-terminator, by definition, would be at the end of the line and there would be nothing after it by virtue of the fact that it marks the end of the line.

If the file contains something along the lines of:

```
key1
value1
key2
value2
```

then you can read those one at a time.